# JS How to make a new method to an Array using prototype but with a function that takes no parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, prototype

I want to extend the Array with a new method called square() which returns a new array with all the numbers squared. I tried making it but I can't figure out a way in which the function **does not take any parameters like the default JS Array methods**. For example `array.reverse()` returns the array reversed it doesn't take the array as the parameter, like this: `array.reverse(array)`
This is my code:

```
Array.prototype.square = function(Array){
    let a = []
    for (let num of Array){
        a.push(num**2)
    }
    return a
}
```

Comment: it's confusing: you want to find a new array or change the existing array? (like the reverse method does)?

Comment: I want to return a new array using the new prototype method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword inside of your function and it will refer to the array calling it.

```js
Array.prototype.square = function() {
  return this.map(number => number ** 2)
}

let test = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(test.square())
```

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track, it can be easily done like this:

```
Array.prototype.square = function () {
    return this.map((number) => number * number)
}

let a = [1, 2]; // sample array

console.log(a.square()); // prints [1, 4]
```

I have used map, which makes the process extremely easy. Refer to this for more information: [Array Map Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

for the record...
*(the name of this kind of added method is called a wrapper)*

```js
/* ---  Array.square  wrapper--- */
if (!Array.prototype.square)  // check that the square method does not already exist 
  {
  Array.prototype.square = function(){ return this.map(x=>x**2) } 
  }
let arr1 = [1,2,3,5,7]
  , arr2 = arr1.square()
  ;
console.log('arr1 ->', JSON.stringify( arr1 ))
console.log('arr2 ->', JSON.stringify( arr2 ))
```

Comment: I didn't know about the JSON.stringify method which seems to be rather useful when console logging, thanks for letting me know, could you think of any more useful methods like that in JS?

Comment: @tarikbog you also have [console.table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/table)

Answer (score 1):

When you add methods to a prototype the object/array will always be the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). So you can simply loop over `this`.

(Aside: it's often good to check that the method doesn't already exist on the prototype which is why I included that code too.)

```js
if (!('square' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.square = function() {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      arr.push(this[i] ** 2);
    }
    return arr;
  }
}

console.log([1, 2, 3].square());
```

Or, more simply, use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return a new array.

```js
if (!('square' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.square = function() {
    return this.map(el => el ** 2);
  }
}

console.log([1, 2, 3].square());
```